# Cassandra Hector Load balancing

Tags: java, cassandra, hector

I have setup a Cassandra cluster with two nodes recently. The replication factor is set to 2 and they both seem to be working well if both the nodes are turned on.
Now how can I use hector in such a way so that it keeps working as far as atleast one node is up? As of now I have something like following.

```
CassandraHostConfigurator cassandraHostConfigurator = new CassandraHostConfigurator(
       "localhost:9160,xx.xx.13.22:9160");
cassandraHostConfigurator.setMaxActive(20);
cassandraHostConfigurator.setMaxIdle(5);
cassandraHostConfigurator.setCassandraThriftSocketTimeout(3000);
cassandraHostConfigurator.setMaxWaitTimeWhenExhausted(4000);
Cluster cluster = HFactory.getOrCreateCluster("structspeech",
   cassandraHostConfigurator);
Keyspace keyspace = HFactory.createKeyspace("structspeech", cluster);
....
```

Let's say if host xx.xx.13.22 goes down then I am getting the following message in my console and all my inserts are failing untill that node comes up.

```
Downed xx.xx.13.22(xx.xx.13.22):9160 host still appears to be down: Unable to open transport to xx.xx.13.22(xx.xx.13.22):9160 , java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

This is how my keyspace is defined

```
 update keyspace structspeech with placement_strategy = 
'org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy' 
 and strategy_options =[{replication_factor:2}];
```

I am sure I am missing something very trivial, any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default Hector uses a consistency level of Quorum so if one of your nodes is down this level cannot be satisfied.
When RF = 2 quorum means you need to read and write to both nodes, so if one of them is down you can't execute.
Here's a nice online tool that demonstrates NRW (N = replication factor, R = read consistency and W = write consistency) http://www.ecyrd.com/cassandracalculator/
To change the consistency level while writing/reading use, for example [AllOneConsistencyLevelPolicy](https://github.com/rantav/hector/blob/master/core/src/main/java/me/prettyprint/cassandra/model/AllOneConsistencyLevelPolicy.java) `HFactory.createKeyspace(String, Cluster, ConsistencyLevelPolicy)`

Answer (score 1):

What consistency level are you using when you insert?  If you are writing at QUORUM or ALL, you need both nodes to be up to write with a replication factor of 2 (a quorum for 2 nodes is 2, that's why typical cassandra clusters use an odd number for replication factor)

Comment: I am so new to this, can you please tell me how can I set it up and what is the ideal number for a cluster of two...

Comment: There are some notes here, http://www.datastax.com/docs/0.8/consistency/index . What consistency level depends on your use case, but a good starting point is a cluster of 3, with replication factor of 3, and read and write at QUORUM, this lets you survive a single node failure.